# How to use JOIN in advance MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, join

So I have been struggling with this question for a while, and trying to figure out the best way to use JOIN to get the answer of finding the "CertCount" per planet.  I know that it wants to have it GROUP BY planets, but I have no clue where planets comes from.  Here is the question and code below:

Find the number of certifications held by people grouped by planet. This should have two columns the first, "name" will be the names of planets that have at least one certification. The second column should be "CertCount" and will be the number of certifications held by people from that planet for example if Lee is certified in "Viper" and "Mechanic" and Kara is certified in "Viper" and they are both from Caprica, then the "CertCount" for caprica should be 3:

```
CREATE TABLE `bsg_cert` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `bsg_cert_people` (
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `pid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cid`,`pid`),
  KEY `pid` (`pid`),
  CONSTRAINT `bsg_cert_people_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`cid`) REFERENCES     `bsg_cert` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `bsg_cert_people_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`pid`) REFERENCES     `bsg_people` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `bsg_people` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `fname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `homeworld` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `age` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `homeworld` (`homeworld`),
  CONSTRAINT `bsg_people_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`homeworld`) REFERENCES     `bsg_planets` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB

CREATE TABLE `bsg_planets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `population` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `language` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `capital` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

So for the moment: I have the following:

```
SELECT  bsg_planets.name ,
   COUNT(*) AS CertCount
FROM bsg_cert_people people_cert
```

I know that I am missing some code, but I'm not sure where to go from here, and could use a little nudge in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join the table according to their primary and foreign key and then do the `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT  ps.id, 
        ps.name ,
        COUNT(distinct *) AS CertCount
FROM bsg_cert_people cp
JOIN bsg_people pe ON cp.pid = pe.id
JOIN bsg_planets ps ON pe.homeworld = ps.id
GROUP BY ps.id, ps.name
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to do inner join among all 3 tables based on common ids of tables and then group by with Planet id.

Following query should work:

```
SELECT ps.name ,
       count(cert.cid) AS CertCount
FROM bsg_cert_people cert
JOIN bsg_people people ON cert.pid = people.id
JOIN bsg_planets planet ON people.homeworld = planet.id
GROUP BY plsnet.id
having count(distinct *) > 0;
```

Hope it helps!